# Is it possible to create a separate class where all your Java-XML linking code stays?

Tags: java, android, class

What I have tried?
I created a manifestUI() method and initialised all UI components and its working well. But I want to put the code for declaring and creating (as well as linking) UI to java code to a separate class, UICreation.java file. I copied all my code in the latter file and corrected small errors due to the code migration but it's not working out.

Objective: Keep the MainActivity.class lean and clean.

Do you think this will make the App function any quicker, slower or no effect whatsoever?

What I am trying to achieve, in a snapshot
[image: Goal]

Using UICreation class in MainActivity.java (I suspect I am doing something wrong here perhaps)

```
UICreation linkUI = new UICreation();
linkUI.manifestUI();
```

Core Code:

```
//Link XML UI with Java: This method imparts the knowledge of the UI link to the compiler
 private void manifestUI() {

// Link TextViews
   bigText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.big_text);
   expressionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expression_text);

// Link Keypad
   zeroKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_zero);
   oneKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_one);
   twoKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_two);
   threeKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_three);
   fourKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_four);
   fiveKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_five);
   sixKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_six);
   sevenKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_seven);
   eightKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_eight);
   nineKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_nine);
   decimalKey = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_decimal);
   backSpaceKey = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);

    // Link Operators
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_subtract);
    multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_multiply);
    divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_divide);
    percentage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_percentage);
    squareRoot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_squareroot);
    operators = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
    }
```

After I moved it to a separate class UI Creation

public class UICreation extends Activity {

```
//Declaring Key as Global Variables
protected Button zeroKey;
protected Button oneKey;
protected Button twoKey;
protected Button threeKey;
protected Button fourKey;
protected Button fiveKey;
protected Button sixKey;
protected Button sevenKey;
protected Button eightKey;
protected Button nineKey;
protected Button decimalKey;
protected ImageButton backSpaceKey;

//Declaring TextView as Global Variables
protected TextView expressionText;
protected TextView bigText;

//Declaring Operators as Global Variables
protected Button add;
protected Button subtract;
protected Button multiply;
protected Button divide;
protected Button percentage;
protected Button squareRoot;

protected HorizontalScrollView operators;

//Link XML UI with Java: This method imparts the knowledge of the UI link to the compiler
protected void manifestUI() {

    //setContentView(R.layout.calculator_ui_responsive);
    // Link TextViews
    bigText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.big_text);
    expressionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expression_text);

    // Link Keypad
    zeroKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_zero);
    oneKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    twoKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_two);
    threeKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_three);
    fourKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_four);
    fiveKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_five);
    sixKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_six);
    sevenKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_seven);
    eightKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_eight);
    nineKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_nine);
    decimalKey = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_decimal);
    backSpaceKey = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);

    // Link Operators
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_subtract);
    multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_multiply);
    divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_divide);
    percentage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_percentage);
    squareRoot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_squareroot);
    operators = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
}}
```

Disclaimer: I am a product designer by profession and new to the exciting world of development.  Please don't be tough on me ;)

Comment: Forgive the "public class UICreation extends Activity {" for being a regular text. Have been trying for an hour to set it right but stackOverFlow isn't letting me do it. Please ignore. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would do this but in android development, views are only avaialable  starting from onCreate(). In the first image/doddle you got that right and called manifsetUI() method in onCreate(). Moving the code to another class is where you went wrong, It's a bad idea.

If you want to remove the hassle of instantiating views, there are several ways to do that now, for example you can get direct access using things like Kotlin Synthetics if you were using Kotlin or viewBinding which is also available for Java

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Is there another method of instantiating views that is better in performance. Or is this (manifestUI()) the best in performance and speed?

Comment: ViewBinding doesn’t have any build time speed impact since it does not use annotation processors. I suggest you use that. you can read about it more here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding